# What are the closed points of $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^2 = \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{R}[x,y])$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, affine-schemes, zariski-topology

I am trying to find all the closed points of $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^2$.

After a quick google research, I found that $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^2 = \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{R}[x,y])$ and then all we need to find is the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$.

However, set-theoretically this equalty does not make sense, as we are talking about points and prime ideals.

And more than that, how do I find the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$? Seems hard.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: $\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{R}}$ is not the same as Spec($\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$). You can identify points $(a,b) \in \mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{R}}$ with the maximal ideal $\langle X-a,Y-b \rangle$ so that $\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{R}} \subsetneq$ Spec($\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$).

Comment: @ET93 If $k$ is not algebraically closed, it is problematic (and uncommon) to define $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ as $k^n$.

Comment: @Slade: You've made me curious: why is it problematic, and how is it done properly?

Comment: @AlexM. One reason is exactly that the maximal ideals of the polynomial ring no longer correspond to closed points.  I would define $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ to be the quotient of $\mathbb{A}_{\overline{k}}^n$ by the action of the Galois group, so that the maximal ideals and the closed points are the same.

Comment: @Slade: Oh, I see: for instance, $\Bbb Z / (2)$ has just $2$ points, while $\Bbb Z / (2) [X]$ has infinitely many maximal ideals (i.e. irreducible polynomials), right?

Comment: @AlexM. Yes, that's a good example for several reasons.  If $k$ is finite, then $k^n$ will be a disconnected space, but our intuition is that affine space should be irreducible.

Comment: @Slade: In light of your explanations, then, why do we call $\Bbb R^n$ "the affine space over $\Bbb R$", given that $\Bbb R$ is not algebraically closed? In particular, the maximal ideal $(X^2 + 1) \in \Bbb R[X]$ doesn't correspond to any point of $\Bbb R$. Is it incorrectly done just for historical reasons? I ask because in my freshman year we defined the affine and projective spaces over arbitrary fields in the "naive" way, ignoring the difficulties that you point out.

Comment: Ravi Vakil, in his notes/book, $\textit{Foundations of Algebraic Geometry}$, defines $\mathbb A^n_A$ as $\operatorname{Spec}A[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ where $A$ is an arbitrary ring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a more direct and canonical approach than the first one I posted:

First, an important fact: if $R=k[X,Y]$, and $\mathfrak{m} \subset R$ is a maximal ideal, then the field $R/\mathfrak{m}$ is a finite extension of $k$.  This is known as [Zariski's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma), and it's the "hard" part of the Nullstellensatz, though there is at least one [very short proof](https://mathoverflow.net/a/50836/1770) for general $k$, and a [one-line proof](https://mathoverflow.net/a/15232/1770) when $k=\mathbb{R}$.

Now, we can make quick work of this problem.  Since $R/\mathfrak{m}$ is a finite extension of $k$, we can identify $R/\mathfrak{m}$ with a subfield of $K$, an algebraic closure of $k$. (When $k=\mathbb{R}$, we have $K=\mathbb{C}$, which you might know as the [fundamental theorem of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra)).

Identify the cosets $X + \mathfrak{m},Y+\mathfrak{m}$ with $a,b\in K$, let $p(X)$ be the minimal polynomial for $a$ over $k$, and let $q(X,Y)$ be the minimal polynomial for $b$ over $k[a]$, considered as a polynomial in $Y$ with coefficients in $k[1,X,\ldots , X^{(\deg p) - 1}]$.  Clearly, $p(a)=q(a,b)=0$, so $p,q\in\ker(R\to R/\mathfrak{m})=\mathfrak{m}$

I claim that $\mathfrak{m} = (p,q)$.  Indeed, if $f\in R$, then there is a unique $g\in f+(p,q)$ with $\deg_X g<\deg p$ and $Y$ degree $\deg_Y g<\deg q$ (use the polynomial division algorithm twice).

If $f\in\mathfrak{m}$, then $g\in\mathfrak{m}$, so $g(a,b)=0$.  By the definition of the minimal polynomial, $g(a,Y)=0$.  By the same definition applied to the coefficients of $g\in (k[X])[Y]$, we have $g(X,Y)=0$.  In other words, $f\in (p,q)$.

---

When $k=\mathbb{R}$, we can be very concrete:

- If $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, then $p=X-a$, $q=Y-b$.
- If $a\in\mathbb{R}$ but $b\notin\mathbb{R}$, then $p=X-a$, $q=(Y-b)(Y-\overline{b})$
- If $a\notin\mathbb{R}$, then $1$ and $a$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$, so we can pick $c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ with $ca+d=b$.  Then $p=(X-a)(X-\overline{a})$, $q=Y-(cX+d)$.

---

My original suggested approach:

- Classify the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ using the Nullstellensatz.
- Show that every maximal ideal of $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ is the restriction of a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$.
- Describe when different maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ restrict to the same maximal ideal of $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$. (Hint: the number of maximal ideals above a given one is either $1$, or $2$.)

This proof is somehow more "geometric" than the one above, more natural but requiring more difficult tools.  Here is how it goes:

The inclusion $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]\hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ induces a morphism $f:\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{R}$, which is surjective because it is the base change to $\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{Z}$ of the surjective morphism $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}\to\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}$.

If $\mathfrak{m}\in\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{R}$ is a closed point with residue field $\kappa$, then the fiber $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{m})$ can be identified with the fiber product $\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{C} \times_{\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{R}} \operatorname{Spec} \kappa \cong \operatorname{Spec} (\mathbb{C}[X,Y]\otimes_{\mathbb{R}[X,Y]} \kappa) \cong \operatorname{Spec}(\kappa)$ or $\operatorname{Spec}(\kappa\times \kappa)$, depending on whether $\kappa=\mathbb{R}$ or $\kappa=\mathbb{C}$.

So each fiber has either one or two points, corresponding to a real point $(a,b)$ , or a pair of conjugate points $\{(c,d),(\overline{c},\overline{d})\}$.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Before posting the question I found this ''proof'': http://mathhelpforum.com/advanced-algebra/68149-maximal-ideal-r-x-y.html but it is incomplete and some arguments are not justified, for example, it is said that $f$ is irreducible but some lines after this we find ''if deg f is even, then f is a product of some irreducible quadratic polynomials in R[x]''... What do you think to be the easiest proof?

Comment: @Leafar That argument is indeed a mess, and mostly likely it's just wrong.  I've updated with my own proof, which I believe to be the simplest approach.  One way or another it seems impossible to avoid using the Nullstellensatz, the fundamental theorem of algebra, and two applications of polynomial division.

Comment: That's a very nice answer, thanks for posting it. Probably the ''more direct and canonical approach'' is the best for me.

Comment: Now that I had time to inspect your answer, what is the relation between $a,b$ and $\mathfrak{m}$? Is $\overline{p}$ the conjugate of $p$? (3rd paragraph: Identify ...)

Comment: @Leafar It was intended to be a coset.  Since I just noticed that I used \overline to mean three completely different things, I've cleaned up the notation a bit.  The only remaining overlines are complex conjugation.

Comment: After reading with attention and after some examples, I don't understand why $g(a,Y)=0$ and therefore $g(X,Y)=0$. I mean, $g(X,Y)=f(X,Y)+h_1(X,Y)p(X)+h_2(X,Y)q(X,Y)$, so $g(a,Y)=f(a,Y)+h_2(a,Y)q(a,Y)$, since $p(a)=0$. Why is $g(a,Y)=0$?

Comment: @Leafar $g(a,b)=0$ implies that $g(a,Y)$ divides $q(a,Y)$.  But $\deg_Y g < \deg_Y q$.

Comment: Ok, I forgot that $f \in \mathfrak{m}$. So now it's clear. I have only one more doubt. How we define $q(X,Y)$. For example, take $a=1+i$ and $b=3+4i$. Then, $p(X)=X^2-2X+2 \in \mathbb{R}[X]$. Is $q(X,Y)=Y-4a+1$? Or $q(X,Y)=Y-4X+1$?

Comment: @Leafar $q$ has coefficients in $k=\mathbb{R}$, while $a$ is complex, so $q(X,Y)=Y-4a+1$ is not a possibility.  We have $q(X,Y) = Y-4X+1$.  There is a unique $q\in k[X,Y]$, with the degree condition I stated, such that $q(a,Y)$ is the minimal polynomial for $b$ over $k[a]$, since the coefficients have unique preimages in $k[1,X,\ldots,X^{(\deg p)-1}]$.

Comment: I'm confused when you say that $g(a,b)=0$ implies that $g(a,Y) | q(a,Y)$ I said that it was clear, but I was thinking wrongly. Sorry, maybe I am being annoying... What you say is true iff $f(a,Y)=0$. But is this true? I don't see why $f(a,Y)$ must be $0$.

Comment: @Leafar For any $h\in k[X,Y]$, $h(a,b)=0 \iff h\mapsto 0\in K \iff h\in \mathfrak{m}$.  And $f\in\mathfrak{m}$ by assumption.

Comment: Ok, but that I already know, because $f(X,Y)+\mathfrak{m}=f(a,b)$, writing $f$ in the form $\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}X^iY^j$. What do we get from here?

Comment: @Leafar We chose $g\in f + (p,q) \subset f+\mathfrak{m}$, so $f\in\mathfrak{m} \implies g\in\mathfrak{m}\implies g(a,b)=0$

Comment: Is this true?: $g(a,b)=0 \Rightarrow g$ annihilates $b$ over $\mathbb{R}[a]$. As $deg_Y(g) < deg_Y(q)$ and $q(a,Y)$ is the minimal polynomial of $b$ over $\mathbb{R}[a]$, we have $g(a,Y)=0$

Comment: @Leafar That's right.

Comment: What a nice answer (actually two answers) : bravo, Slade!

Answer (score 3):

Re:

> However, set-theoretically this equalty does not make sense, as we are talking about points and prime ideals.

The points of a scheme are*, by definition, prime ideals of a ring.  If this is new to you, you're probably not ready to be looking at this question until you go back and learn what a scheme is.

Once you understand the question, Slade's answer shows you a good way of working the problem.

*Or, if you want to be incredibly pedantic, *correspond to* the ideals of a ring, since a scheme is a locally ringed space that *happens to be* locally isomorphic to the spectrum of a ring.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I learned scheme theory last month by Gathmann's notes and I'm trying to do some exercises of that notes. My problem was the identification between those two objects, but $Spec(\mathbb{R}[x,y])$ contains the maximal ideals $(x-a,y-b)$ which correspond to the points of the real plane $(a,b)$ and we can see $Spec(\mathbb{R}[x,y])$ as the points of the affine plane and some ''invisible points'' (called generic points). I think that the idea of the main problem is using scheme theory. Your last paragraph is exactly ''my'' definition of a scheme (not the same as affine scheme)

Comment: Be careful -- just because a prime ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ isn't of the form $(x-a, y-b)$ doesn't mean it's not maximal. For instance, consider the ideal $(x^2+1, y)$.  We have $$\mathbb{R}[x, y]/(x^2+1, y) \cong \mathbb{R}[x] / (x^2+1) \cong \mathbb{C},$$ which is a field, so $(x^2+1, y)$ is a maximal ideal, and thus corresponds to a closed point of $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{R}[x, y]$.

Comment: Yes, the main problem is finding the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. In http://mathhelpforum.com/advanced-algebra/68149-maximal-ideal-r-x-y.html I found all of them but I'm trying to understand the proof...

Comment: You seemed to be implying that points like $(x^2+1, y)$ were generic points above, which isn't true.  That's what I was trying to clarify in the previous comment.